# Prefetch & cache dynamically created jqueryMobile+PhoneGap pages

Tags: android, ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a PhoneGap app (with jqueryMobile) which uses several listviews, sometimes with pictures included.
On some devices this can take 1-2 seconds to load. I have tried to use the cache-

```
<div data-role="page" class="listpage" data-dom-cache="true">
```

and prefetch-

```
<a href="listview_1.html" rel="external" data-prefetch>Listview 1</a>
```

options, but neither would work / make any difference.
The pages are almost completely dynamically created from a sqlite database - maybe this is the actual issue...?

Any hints greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Is it pulling the image in locally or over the wire?

Comment: Everything is pulled locally...

Answer (score 0):

I think cache will not solve your problem. cache stores temporarily pages and images, and also mainly for second time load only. Other choice is reduce the **list view count** for example 8 or 10 with load more button or scroll to append new list values use **pagination concept** to load list view. If your using cache concept you can't load new list values so that's not dynamic list view.

Best choice for cache is **list view to navigate detailed view**. Because after user clicks back button or link to retain list view.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really an option. I want the user to see the amount of items, fast and easy, with all the thumbnails included, that just makes the list what it is.I might have to wait for jQM1.4's **data-enhanced**...